# Persistent Style Sheet Switcher with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, themes, switch-statement, stylesheet

I'm rolling out a new style for a web app my company maintains and want to give users the option to revert to the previous style.

I've got the sheets switching just fine, but when navigating to different pages it reverts back to the new stylesheet.

I want it to keep the stylesheet the user chose to use but am not sure how to make that happen.

My Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/style.css" id="style"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/colors.css" id="colors"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/jquery.datepicker.css" id="datepicker"/>

 <!--View Switch-->
     <div id="view">
     <button id="new" class="new">Switch to Classic View</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#new").click(function () {
        jQuery('#style').remove();
        $('head').append('<link href="/Assets/css/style.old.css" rel="stylesheet" id="oldstyle" />');
        jQuery('#colors').remove();
        $('head').append('<link href="/Assets/css/colors.old.css" rel="stylesheet" id="oldcolors" />');
        jQuery('#datepicker').remove();
        $('head').append('<link href="/Assets/css/jquery.datepicker.old.css" rel="stylesheet" id="olddatepicker" />');
    });
</script>
    <button id="old" class="old">Switch to Updated View</button>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $("#old").click(function () {
             jQuery('#oldstyle').remove();
             $('head').append('<link href="/Assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style" />');
             jQuery('#oldcolors').remove();
             $('head').append('<link href="/Assets/css/colors.css" rel="stylesheet" id="colors" />');
             jQuery('#olddatepicker').remove();
             $('head').append('<link href="/Assets/css/jquery.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" id="datepicker" />');
         });  
</script>
</div>
<!-- End View Switch -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a cookie, this is the best way to do this, it will also allow them to leave the site and come back with the changes preserved.

```
setCookie ('stylesheet', 1, 60 * 60 * 24 * 365); //Sets cookie with a value of 1 valid for 1 year

var style = getCookie('stylesheet'); //Gets cookie value
document.getElementById("css").href="css" + style + ".css";
```

Comment: Might as well store the entire stylesheet URL in the cookie, while you're at it. +1 if you rewrite your answer so that it runs in the original poster's code.